# How to change Android app name?

Tags: android

I want to change android application name programatically. Is there any API to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You cant do that. But WHY?, follow the standards.

Comment: ignore, I don't know where I found a citation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant do it pragmatically.its static.Go to menifest file and add android:label="Your application name" in application tag like below

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Your application name">
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the app name programatically. It is in the manifest. Why do you want to do that anyways?

Comment: +1 ^^... just imagine the possibilities if it could be changed :D

Answer (score 4):

You could try to change the name using Antscripts, but this could just happen during devTime.
The appname itself does stand in the manifest.xml:

```
<application android:label="My App name">
```

Mostly its refered to the `R.String` file.
Otherwise as codeBegin already said, use `setTitle("AppName")` to change the title in the current activity.

If you really want to change the name of the WHOLE app, this would NOT be possible, just imagine what a chaos will be created if apps are renamed frequently ;)